# Length in Text Editor

Tags: python

apparently after i typed len(locations) into my atom text editor. the length did not show up! Can someone help me? I can type len(locations) into command prompt  but the after typing into text editor and saving, it did not work!

```
print("Original order:")
print(locations)
print('n/Alphabetical order:')
print(sorted(locations))
print("n\Reverse alphabetical:")
print(sorted(locations, reverse = True))
print("\nOriginal order:")
print(locations)
print("\nReversed:")
locations.reverse()
print(locations)
print("\nAlphabetical")
locations.sort()
print(locations)
print("\nReverse alphabetical")
locations.sort(reverse=True)
print(locations)
len(locations)

Output: ['himalaya', 'andes', 'tierra', 'labrador', 'guam']
n/Alphabetical order:
['andes', 'guam', 'himalaya', 'labrador', 'tierra']
n\Reverse alphabetical:
['tierra', 'labrador', 'himalaya', 'guam', 'andes']

Original order:
['himalaya', 'andes', 'tierra', 'labrador', 'guam']

Reversed:
['guam', 'labrador', 'tierra', 'andes', 'himalaya']

Alphabetical
['andes', 'guam', 'himalaya', 'labrador', 'tierra']

Reverse alphabetical
['tierra', 'labrador', 'himalaya', 'guam', 'andes']
```

Comment: Did you want to print the length of `locations`? Did you mean `print(len(locations))` instead?

Comment: Why do  you think that the text editor should provide interactive functionality, just as your IDE command line does?  It seems that you need to read teh documentation for each.

Comment: in normal script you have to use `print()` to see values. Only `Python Shell` (python in interactive mode) or Jupyter display automatically all results.

Comment: @Prune Is is a very common beginner mistake not to understand the difference between a REPL environment and a program. Which is partly because all of the tutorial material begins with the REPL environment, and that leads beginners to think that everything works like a `>>>` prompt. That's why.

Comment: @j3st I want to print the length of locations! yes youre right. but if i typed len(locations) on command prompt it will show up 5. In the text editor, len(location) do not show up 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the length of locations in your program, then do so with the `print` function.

Your command shell (an interactive IDE running the Python interpreter) has a side effect that, if a line of code returns a value other than `None`, the IDE will display that value.  It's a courtesy of the IDE, not part of the Python language.

This actually devolves from the early days of programming, when functional programming was popular in computer science programs.  There, functions do not have side effects: they simply return the needed value.  The goal of the program is to return the *entire* result as the final value of the main function.  Therefore, the programming environment was responsible to display that final value.

Programmers found this useful enough in debugging, that the practice has continued.